# Connect link failure MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, rest, spring-boot

I'm working my project for deploying Spring Boot + REST.
Application requires to have database which is used MySQL.
My app has apache tomcat 9.0.12 version.
I have tried to build run as java application, and system reports error message:

```
    2018-09-25 23:14:23.398  INFO 21112 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 8286 ms
2018-09-25 23:14:23.897  INFO 21112 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2018-09-25 23:14:23.905  INFO 21112 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-09-25 23:14:23.907  INFO 21112 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-09-25 23:14:23.907  INFO 21112 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-09-25 23:14:23.907  INFO 21112 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-09-25 23:14:27.248 ERROR 21112 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create initial connections of pool.

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar:5.1.42]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:989) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar:5.1.42]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:341) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar:5.1.42]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2192) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar:5.1.42]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2225) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar:5.1.42]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2024) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar:5.1.42]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:779) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar:5.1.42]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar:5.1.42]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar:5.1.42]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:389) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar:5.1.42]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:330) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar:5.1.42]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:310) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:735) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:667) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:482) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:154) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111) [spring-jdbc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77) [spring-jdbc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:326) [spring-jdbc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:366) [spring-jdbc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup.getDatabase(DatabaseLookup.java:72) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties.determineDatabase(JpaProperties.java:139) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.jpaVendorAdapter(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:105) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c22a218.CGLIB$jpaVendorAdapter$10(<generated>) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c22a218$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$938fdb3d.invoke(<generated>) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) [spring-core-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358) [spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c22a218.jpaVendorAdapter(<generated>) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
```

Too many lines...

Please tell me for helping how to connect spring boot with DB. THANKS.

Comment: It seems like your MySQL server is not reachable. What is the hostname/IP address it is running? What is the terminal output for `telnet hostname/IP 3306`?

Comment: application.properties:

## Spring DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties)
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/world?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = varun123



## Hibernate Properties
# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

Comment: Can you write the output to `telnet localhost 3306`. Is your MySQL server up and running on your `localhost`?

Comment: Cmd repied:
C:\WINDOWS\system32>telnet localhost 3306
Connecting To localhost...Could not open connection to the host, on port 3306: Connect failed

Comment: You don't have your MySQL server up and running on your `localhost`. Get it up and running, and it will work just fine. And I wouldn't necessarily put my username and password online like in your first comment.

Comment: Now, I understand about everything.
Thank you for advice.
One question,
How to create MySql server? This I should download MySql server app?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installation-excerpt/5.7/en/windows-installation.html And you should create a database with name `world` and `root` user with password `varun123`.

Comment: Yes!!! It is working on web application.
Thank you ;)

Comment: Try creating a DataSource in your IDE with the DB details and try pinging the Database. Mention URL,Username,Password .This way you can save time by just pinging the Database and you do not need to run your application to verify.

Answer (score 1):

To wrap up the comments:

Your MySQL server is not listening to connections on `localhost` port `3306`. You need to install it, and can find reference for Windows installation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installation-excerpt/5.7/en/windows-installation.html). And given your config:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/world?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username = root spring.datasource.password = varun123
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

You need to create a database named `world` and root user with password `varun123` will be able to access it.